# How can I turn a bowl/glass upside down?

Tags: motor, robotic-arm, actuator

I want to dispense water/cut-vegetables from a glass/bowl(240 ml) by turning it upside down. The screencast shows the idea:

[image: Idea]

I can directly mount the clamp on a servo motor, but I think that will be a lot put a lot of downward force on the shaft. What will be a good mechanical arrangement to do this? Thanks!

Ref:

1. Servo MG996R with Metal Gears
2. Cup:

[image: cup img]

Answer (score 2):

## Here's an idea

[image: Bowl Rotation Concept]

## Explanation

Instead of the servo bearing the weight, there is an axis through the bowl that the servo is attached to. This takes all of the strain off of the servo. The servo arm is attached to the bowl and rotates the bowl on the shaft through the bowl.

Answer (score 0):

You can take the shear force onto a bearing housing. And the servo can only deal with the rotation of the bowl.

To do so, you need a bearing which carries the mass of the load (bowl). And through this bearing a shaft is attached onto the bowl. And the servo drives this shaft.

Two bearings at each side would make the system more stable, and possibly decrease any extra friction due to the bending moments.